# Typewriter animation in css

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

Hi I'm trying to get a simple typewriting animation to work in CSS, this is my first big project so I don't really want to include any jQuery or much JavaScript, but can include JavaScript if have to, I'm just using html and sass so far for this webpage, I have the animation working but it doesn't go from left to right on the text that is on the left side of the screen.

TLDR: got animation working but it wont go from left to right on the text that is on the left half of the screen.

```
    .anim_write-1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;   
    margin-left: 11rem;  
    }
    /* Animation */
    .anim_write-1 {
    animation: animated-text 2s steps(30,end) 0s 1 normal both;
    }
```

[Want the shop now and get inspired stuff to go from left to right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuZUK.gif)

Comment: you have to share your work (code) so far so we can help you

Comment: Please read [ask]. It's got a ton of tips that will help you get the most out of Stack Overflow.